# How to display a progress / please wait type component while waiting for a long POST request

Tags: java, css, spring-boot, jsp, progress-bar

I am building a web app that includes some features that can take a few seconds to complete such as importing 2000+ entities after clicking on a link.

One such feature first has the user choose a CSV file, uploads it to the server and then iterates through it line by line to create the associated entities and save them in the database.

Here is an example of how the JSP page looks :

JSP

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<c:url value="/import/importFormulary" /> " class="form-style-7">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label> File : </label>
                    <input type="file" name="file" accept=".csv"/>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload and Import" />
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
        </form>
```

I would like the submission of this form to trigger some sort of "please wait" overlay on the page.  Something like this would be REALLY nice :  http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/

I understand the "waiting for localhost" message is the controller doing its thing in the background which means the page this form is on is technically not active anymore.  Knowing that fact, i'm struggling to figure out how to implement this.  I have a place in my app where i do an AJAX request every second to refresh the content of a table and I have a feeling this is a direction to explore in order to achieve the result i want but seeing an example of a similar thing being done would be very helpful.

How does one show a spinning circle of please wait on the current page while waiting for the underlying controller to finish processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I settled with something like this, courtesy of font awesome :

```
<a th:href = "@{'/export/formularyAdd/' + ${facility.id}}" class="btn btn-outline-info eBtn" 
    title="Export Formulary Add Messages" onclick="showPleaseWait()">
```

Wrote this function in an included JS file :

```
function showPleaseWait()
{
    $('.modal').modal('show');
}

<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content" style="width: 200px;">
            <span class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-5x fa-fw" style="width: 200px;"></span>
            <p class="please-wait-message">Please wait</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The following import is on my page :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css}"/>
```

And finally this maven import :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This lets the controller do its thing and displays the progress spinner until the page is redirected.